# Wrong format of WIndows path in CURDIR, GNU Make 4.3

Tags: makefile, gnu, absolute-path

I have a problem getting a valid absolute address in my Makefile. I need to migrate from GNU Make 3.81 to 4.3.
When using this:

```
PROJECT_DIR = $(subst \,/,${CURDIR})/..
```

Instead of something like:

```
D:/Project/What_ever/
```

I'm getting this:

```
/d/Project/What_ever
```

I need the absolute address for some external tools.
And of course the /d/... is not the Windows format really.

Comment: Looks like your newer version of GNU make is not compiled as a native Windows application and was instead built using Cygwin or similar.  When I add `$(info CURDIR=$(CURDIR))` to a makefile and build with GNU make 4.3 built using Visual Studio as a native Windows application, it prints `CURDIR=C:/Users/build/make-4.3`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will inform our Tool support who is providing the whole GNU package. When I check the version there is 'Built for x86_64-pc-msys'. This is not correct?

Comment: msys is not correct

Comment: Can you give me a hint on what is correct configuration? In the past, we were using version 3.81 build for 'i386-pc-mingw32'... it was fully ok but now we are missing some features that is why we need to migrate.

Comment: You can search to find the difference between mingw, msys, and cygwin in detail.  But basically, mingw is an environment that allows the GCC compiler to build native windows programs (linked directly with Windows runtime and must use Windows API).  msys and cygwin are ports of POSIX environments to Windows: they allow programs written to the POSIX API to compile and run on Windows without being ported to use the Windows API).  When GNU make is built for native Windows it uses windows paths (more or less).  When GNU make is built for POSIX it uses POSIX paths.

Comment: If you want Windows paths and commands, you should build either with mingw for the GCC compiler, or use the Visual Studio compiler.